# Set of symmetric matrices is a manifold.

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

How do I prove that the set of symmetric matrices is a manifold of dimension $n(n+1)/2.$

I tried it by using Regular value theorem. For that I consider the map $$ f:M(n,\mathbb{R})\to M(n,\mathbb{R}),\ \ A\mapsto A-A^T . $$ Now I need to check following:

1. $f$ is smooth.
2. $Df$ is surjective.

Here I don't know how to calculate $Df$? Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The set of symmetric matrices is a vector space, hence it has one global chart and its dimension is its dimension as a vector space.

Besides, your approach is doomed, $f$  is not a submersion since it is a linear non-invertible map<sup>1</sup>, its kernel is precisely the set of symmetric matrices. More generally, if $0$ is a regular value of $f\colon\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^q$, then $f^{-1}(0)$ is a manifold of dimension $n-q$. Here, it would mean that the set of symmetric matrices has dimension $0$.

If you want to use the regular value theorem, you can prove that the orthogonal group is a manifold of dimension $n(n-1)/2$.

<sup>1: As a linear map, one has $Df\equiv f$, its differential is constant and is equal to $f$, besides $f$ being non-invertible implies that it is not-surjective since it is an endomorphism of a finite-dimensional vector space.</sup>

Comment: I tried with this method because I need to calculate the tangent space at $I$, which is the Kernel of $Df$ map.

Comment: Sure, but you can do it just using the definition of the tangent space at a point. Let $E$ be a vector space and let $v\in E$, then $\gamma(t)=tv$ is a curve drawn of $E$ such that $\gamma(0)=0$ and $\dot{\gamma}(0)=v$, hence $v\in T_0E$ and using dimensions, $T_0E=E$. If you really want to do the computation at the identity matrix, just consider $\gamma(t)=tM+I$, where $M$ is a symmetric matrix.

Comment: okay, thanks. I got it.

Comment: What you need to understand is that a submersion is a set of *independent* equations for your manifold and the number of equations is its codimension. In the case of symmetric matrices, you will need to write $n(n-1)/2$ equations, namely $a_{i,j}=a_{j,i}$ for $1\leqslant i<j\leqslant n$. The map you have written in your post has redundant equations and this is why it failed to be a submersion. Try to meditate these remarks, it will help you to really get a grasp on what you are doing! :)